# Do they make triangle-shaped headers?

Tags: connector, wiring, header, crimp

I've been working with some PIR sensors from Panasonic, and I was wondering if there are any types of female headers/connectors that I could use to wire the three pins of the sensor without directly soldering wires to the connector. I've been looking, but I haven't been able to find any types of connectors which would fit.

Off the top of your head, are there any types of connectors which could be used to easily wire this?

If it helps, the sensor fits into a standard breadboard as in the image below:

[image]

For some more information, here's a link to the digikey part (MFG P/N:)
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/AMN41121/255-1808-ND/735391

And here is a link to the datasheet. All sensors have the same pins at the bottom:
http://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/sensor/human/catalog/bltn_eng_mp.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they would! They're thin, a lot thinner than typical male headers. However, I was looking for something that would be easily connected to wires, whether by crimp or a pre-made cable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TE Connectivity's [8058-1G23](http://www.te.com/catalog/pn/en/1437508-7) is a PCB-mount TO-5 socket that should either fit the sensor or be very, very close. The [-1G29](http://www.te.com/catalog/pn/en/1-1437508-2) is the same but with solder pockets instead.

Comment: In general, any TO-5 socket should fit.

Comment: oh perfect, looks like a TO-5 footprint. That's really helpful. Now I wonder whether they sell cables with female TO-5 already crimped onto one end...

Comment: The solder cup option is probably the easiest if you have to do it yourself.

Comment: The TE socket is ridiculously expensive if you go to try purchasing it. Look instead at this much more cost effective socket for TO-5. http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Mill-Max/917-43-103-41-005000/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs%2fSh%2fkjph1tjJZclYmfaNPDBBt9Pox0Ys%3d

Answer (score 6):

You could use a 2x3 post header connector.